# QGIS web client - Setting up WSGI search (mod_wsgi)

Tags: qgis, qgis-web-client

I am trying to set up the QGIS Web Clients WSGI search. I've succefully set up my QGIS WebClient on a windows OS. Now I tried installing the mod_wsgi.so module in the Apache modules directory, added the line LoadModule modules wsgi_module / mod_wsgi.so always in apache but as soon as I plug in the conf apache:

```
 #mod_wsgi

 WSGIScriptAlias / WSGI "C: \ OSGeo4W \ apache \ htdocs \ qgis-web-client-master \ WSGI"      WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^ / WSGI / ([^ /] +) "C: \ OSGeo4W \ apache \ htdocs \ qgis -Web-client-master \ $ 1.wsgi"
```

The apache server does not reboot. I'd like to understand what am I doing wrong and how to further set up my apache to execute wsgi files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QGIS Web Client's WSGI search requires you to configure your Apache into executing wsgi scripts. Firstly you'll need to install the correct module (When downloading a wsgi module please be sure to check the correct Apache version).

On the windows OS the configuration file can be found in the folder OSGeo4W/apache/conf/httpd.conf

Enable your [module](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/#):

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Now within the file OSGeo4W/httpd.d/httpd_qgis.conf we will configure our qgis application. This folder can contain definitions for qgis or any other kind of applications.

We will be adding 2 definitions, first one is the alias for wsgi:

```
Alias /wsgi/ C:\OSGeo4W/wsgi/  #**NOTE
#This will allow to change the path of the wsgi folder (which contains your wsgi/python scripts) to a shorter one -> /wsgi/
```

The second one is how and where we handle/execute these scripts:

```
<Directory "C:\OSGeo4W/wsgi/">
  SetHandler wsgi-script
  Options ExecCGI
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**NOTE I've moved the wsgi scripts and the qgiswebclient/wsgi folder because the qwc_connect.py contains a database string, which is information I wouldn't like to share with the people using my Apache server

After these simple steps the Apache should reboot. If the Apache successfully rebooted the wsgi scripts are now supported.

The next step is setting up the wsgi scripts inside the /wsgi folder.
In the file qwc_connect.py, we will now need to set up our database string:

```
DB_CONN_STRING="host='hostname' dbname='DATABASE_NAME' port='5432' user='myuser' password='mypassword'"
```

After we got our database string set, it is time to set the searchtables within the file search.wsgi, where we jump to line 32 and set:

```
searchtables = [sheme_name.table_name,...];
```

Now that we have our searchtable names set, we should [define](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Web-Client#623-postgresql-table-setup-for-searching) the [views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createview.html) inside our database. Here is an example of create view script for PostgreSQL from michele's table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_name_here AS --if you're using pgAdmin, remove this line 
SELECT 
concat ('Layer catasto_terreni: ', c.id,'-', c.foglio, '\', c.part_cat, ' ', c.comune) AS displaytext,
--this is the display text in your search box
concat(c.id,'\', c.foglio,'\', c.part_cat, '\', c.comune) AS search_category,
concat(c.part_cat, '/', c.foglio, '/', c.comune) AS searchstring,
--we perform searching by entering values parc_cat/foglio/comune, we can concat them to form more even complex strings, but I use a different view for each "type" of search
concat('') AS showlayer,
c.geom AS the_geom --this field is the most important one since it will zoom to this geometry
FROM catasto_terreni c;
```

This is an example of a search:
    [image: QGIS Web Client search]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53522/discussion-on-answer-by-ena2345-qgis-web-client-setting-up-wsgi-search-mod-ws).

Comment: Oh thanks Midavalo, you can clear those comments up if possible...

Comment: Hello Ena. Where could I find the material with respect to the description of the various text strings: dispalytext, search_category, searchstring, showLayer? Thank you

Comment: You can find all the information here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Web-Client#623-postgresql-table-setup-for-searching

Comment: I had already seen. The problem is that I do not understand exactly what are the searchstring and search_category  functions.

Comment: Well simply put, searchstring is format in which you will search, and category is formed out of your searchstring, to catagorize your results

Comment: Hello Ena. I ask if you can make a query on two different tables. you can take a view that you draw the results from two tables? I would have in a view the results of all fields in a table and a single field in the other table. Thank you

Comment: You can do this in 2 ways, make 2 searchtables, or just add the field from the other table, to the display text in your old view. You can do this using a inner join (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-join.html).

Comment: since QWC the chance to make more than one use the method of multiple views .. unfortunately I do not have much experience in formatting tables .. thanks anyway Ena

Comment: hello Ena.
when I try to search on QWC appears to me a network error. this thing does not happen on a shapefile ("street") downloaded from OpenStreetMap .. for all other levels (eg. "cadastre") when I type in the search box I locates well but appears to me a mistake and I will light the feature .. what can be had? I enclose picture. Thank you http://imageshack.com/a/img924/8163/ab06yi.png

Comment: Hello, if I understand correctly, you get this error when searching layers inside the database? If I remember correctly you had this working without the error before? I would need more information on what you changed in your project, because by default the search is working without problems, so there must either be a problem with your table definition or text within the result of search.

Comment: hello Ena Sorry I'm late .. then:
1) the problem has always been there from the beginning of some layers
2) the getsearchgeom works well on "stradario" layer, downloaded from the OpenStreetMap database.
3) for the other layers type (land register and point of interest) when you make the search locates well but it returns me a errore.E 'boring clear every time the curtain error.
4) what would you need to know to help me?
Thanks Ena

Comment: I think the problem could be with the incorrect coordinate systems, where the OpenStreetMap has the correct coordinate system as in your GlobalOptions file. That is why the search on this layer, but fails to work on your other layers. Also we shouldn't use comments for further discussions I've made this room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55309/qgis-web-client-setting-up-wsgi-search-mod-wsgi